# Approximate a function by Gaussian kernels $e^{-\frac12x^2}$

Tags: numerical-methods, normal-distribution, approximation

Let $d\in\mathbb N$, $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb R^d$ and $\rho:\Omega\to[0,\infty)$. I try to understand the approximation of $p$ described on p. (3) of [this paper](https://www.cs.huji.ac.il/w%7Eraananf/projects/kdm/paper.pdf#page=3).

The author is doing the following: Let $$\varphi(x):=e^{-\frac12x^2}\;\;\;\text{for }x\in\mathbb R$$ (or maybe $\varphi(x):=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac12x^2}$; it's not totally clear from the paper), $$\sigma(x):=\rho(x)^{-\frac1d}\;\;\;\text{for }x\in\Omega,$$ $$\psi(x,y):=\frac1{\sigma(x)^d}\varphi\left(\frac{\|x-y\|}{\sigma(x)}\right)\;\;\;\text{for }x,y\in\Omega$$ and $$A(x,y):=\sum_{i=1}^n\psi(x_i,y)\;\;\;\text{for }x\in\Omega^n\text{ and }y\in\Omega.$$

> The author is claiming that, given $x\in\Omega^n$, we can approximate $\rho$ by $A(x,\;\cdot\;)$.

He even shows an illustrative example for $d=1$:
[image]

> Now simply assume that $\rho=1$. We easily see that Gaussian kernels have overlapping support. In the example above, we see that only for every $i\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$, only a single kernel does not vanish at $x_i$. So, shouldn't we somehow need to incorporate the distances between the $x_i$ in order to ensure that the supports are suitably?

Without that, $A(x,\;\cdot\;)$ is obviously not necessarily an approximation of $\rho=1$. Simply take $x_i=\frac in$ and $n=100$. Then, for example,

```
y = 0:          A(x, y) = 33.2128
y = 0.01:       A(x, y) = 33.3673
y = 0.02:       A(x, y) = 33.5193
y = 0.03:       A(x, y) = 33.6689
y = 0.04:       A(x, y) = 33.8159
y = 0.05:       A(x, y) = 33.9602
y = 0.06:       A(x, y) = 34.102
y = 0.07:       A(x, y) = 34.2411
y = 0.08:       A(x, y) = 34.3775
y = 0.09:       A(x, y) = 34.5111
```

Comment: I had to read the question twice to find the actual question being asked here, which has been cleverly hidden inside a block quote. Since nothing is being quoted there, I would suggest getting rid of the (misleading, IMHO) block quote, and instead using emphasis to highlight the actual question.